# How to record the finding of 10 dollars lying on the street and their subsequent placement into one's wallet (in gnucash)?

Tags: accounting, income, gnucash, double-entry

Within **`gnucash`**:

within the `Cash in Wallet` account:

- `description:` **found some money in the street**
- `transfer:` **Imbalance-USD** or create a *new* arbitrary one-off account called something like "**Penny Lane**" or "**Gift from above**"???

What are the options for doing this correctly? What are the lazy options? What would be considered best-practice?

<sub>I'm ***not*** interested in a moral discussion here about what to do with the 10 dollars... this is for learning the ropes of accounting, only :-)</sub>

Comment: Why record it at all? That's my preferred lazy way

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE shoyu.  Please read the [help] page.  We don't generally support accounting, but this may be on topic.

Comment: @C.Ross Shame, I think SE is well cut out for an accounting Q&A... and http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41474/accounting doesn't seem to have made it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's income. Create an income account for it, or use a broader “miscellaneous income” account, depending on how precise you want to be.

Comment: I used to think that if it 'came from above' I should use it for good. So I find $10, and pass it on to the next homeless person I see. But a gift to an individual is not a deduction, so I have $10 that I have to pay tax on, as I'm told the 5 second rule only applies to dropped food, not found money you give away.

Comment: If the taxman pressed me on this, I would claim that I was merely an agent passing the ten dollars on to another person, and that it didn't count as income to me.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer How would the tax man find out? That's usually what I do when I find money on the street, so should I be worried that I haven't reported it? Oh boy...

Comment: Not claiming such income is a criminal matter and discussion or encouragement of such behavior is prohibited on these boards. :P